# silex mount only if user have access

Tags: silex

First, sorry, I don't speak english very well. I use Silex and I want to mount ControllerProvider only if users have access to this part of the application.
In app.php, I have a service which creates a user with all modules he has access to.

```
$app['utilisateur'] = function() use ($app){
    $utilisateurToken =    UtilisateurController::getUserByToken($app['security.token_storage']);
    if ($utilisateurToken->isAnnonyme())
    {
        $utilisateur = $utilisateurToken;
        $module_repository = new ModuleRepository($app['db_intranet_v3']);
        $modules = $module_repository->find();
        $utilisateur->addModules($modules);
    }
    else
    {
        $utilisateur = UtilisateurController::getUserByIdWithModules($app,$utilisateurToken->getId());
    }
    return $utilisateur;
};
```

Then, I mount each module 'manually' :

```
$app->mount('/exampleModule', new exampleModuleControllerProvider());
```

Is it possible to automatically mount the module in the service? When I try, I have an error : "Unable to generate a URL for the named route "exampleModule" as such route does not exist."
Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution is very easy. The error tells you it can't find a route with the name `exampleModule`, so we should give him the route with that name.

We can define a named route using `bind`, so your route should be mounted in this way:

```
$app->mount('/exampleModule', new exampleModuleControllerProvider())->bind('exampleModule');
```

More info can be found on [this page in the documentation](https://silex.symfony.com/doc/2.0/usage.html#named-routes).